# Motherboard memory question

Tags: memory, motherboard

I am currently drawing up specs on a new workstation for my office. I am considering the [Asus P6X58D](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131614) for a motherboard. This board's specs list it as supporting 24 gigs of memory. Suppose I were to use six [four gig memory cards](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231313) and then two [video cards](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814121333) with 1 gig of memory apiece. Is the maximum supported memory similar to how 32 bit operating systems only have enough address space for 4 gigs of memory?

Simply:

1. Will the board post?
2. If so, will the system be able to address all the memory, both the 24 gigs on the ddr3 bus and the 3 gigs on the graphics card?

Comment: perhaps i wasn't clear, i'm asking about the limitations of the motherboard, not the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

1. If all the hardware is suppoerted, yes
2. If you use a 64 bit OS, then yes

The maximum memory supported by a motherboard only concerns the RAM, the video card memory is completely separate (well, except for onboard video cards that use part of the main memory).

Comment: The video cards are linked in the question and have their own memory.

Answer (score 1):

1. If all hardware is supported/compatible then yes.
2. Only if you are using 64 bit OS. 32-bit OS has a 3.something GB Memory Limit. They aren't designed to use anything past that.

It is important to keep in mind that video card memory is separate from your RAM memory. Video cards have their own memory, unless they are onboard, and share from your RAM. So what this means is, the total amount of system memory is solely from your RAM amount minus whatever amount your onboard-videocardsare taking. It is not possible (from what I know) to do the opposite, and use videocard memory solely as RAM memory.

So really the system will only use the 24-gigs as RAM memory, and use the 3 gigs solely for graphics processing.